# Probability of multiple dice rolls with recursion

Tags: java

How would I go about using recursion to calculate the probability of rolling a certain number, r, with a given number of dice?  I tried to treat this as a choose problem but am still quite confused as to how the algorithm should work.

For example, it should work out to be something like this:

P(4,14)=(1/6)P(3,13)+(1/6)P(3,12)+(1/6)P(3,11)+(1/6)P(3,10)+(1/6)P(3,9)+(1/6)P(3,8)

P(3,8)=(1/6)P(2,7)+(1/6)P(2,6)+(1/6)P(2,5)+(1/6)P(2,4)+(1/6)P(2,3)+(1/6)P(2,2)

P(2,4)=(1/6)P(1,3)+(1/6)P(1,2)+(1/6)P(1,1)+(1/6)P(1,0)+(1/6)P(1,-1)+(1/6)P(1,-2)

=(1/6)(1/6)+(1/6)(1/6)+(1/6)(1/6)+(1/6)(0)+(1/6)(0)+(1/6)(0)

I'm just having trouble converting it into code.

```
static double P(int dice, int r) {
int ret = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
     ret = (1/6)(ret*(dice-i))/(i+1);
}
return ret;
    }  

static double RollDice(int dice,int r) {
     if (dice==1 && (r<1 || r>6)){ 
     return 0;
     }
     if (dice==1 && (r>=1 && r<=6)){
        return (1.0/6);
     }

     else {
        return ((1.0/6)*P(dice-1,r-1));
     }
```

Comment: It's been a while since I did statistics work, but what are you asserting with P(4, 14)?  Why do the delineations occur around (3, 8) and (2, 4)?  I'm very confused.

Comment: looks like homework ;) what is the complete text of your task. i'm not quite sure where to put recursion in just rolling and counting

Comment: By using recursion, we can reduce the problem to the probability of a single die rolling a # between 1 - 6.  Therefore, P(4, 14) can be expressed as the combination of of (1/6)P(3,13) - (1/6)P(3,8) which can again be expressed as (1/6)P(2,7) and such forth until we get to dice = 1.  At least that's my understanding of the problem...

Comment: okay im out. that is way to long ago for me to remember how that works. sorry

Comment: My question more or less was stressing the "why" portion of it.  Why do these functions reduce to that?  What kind of mathematical approach are you using?  If these were simple Bernoulli trials, that'd make no sense (which may be what I'm hung up on).

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you have to separate methods `P()` and `RollDice()`, since in your formulae you (correctly) describe everything with `P`.

If you were to put your formulae into code, it should look something like this:

EDIT: changed the base case to 0 dice, since then it becomes even simpler.

```
static double P(int dice, int r) {
    if (dice == 0) {
        // Zero dice: probabiliy 1 to get 0
        if (r == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        } else {
            return 0.0;
        }
    else {
        // Multiple dice: recursion
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (/* TODO */) {
            sum += //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

For the recursion part, try working it out by looking at the formula:

```
P(4, 14) = (1/6)P(3, 13) + (1/6)P(3, 12) + ... + (1/6)P(3, 8)
```

i.e. in the general case

```
P(dice, r)=(1/6)P(dice-1, r-1) + (1/6)P(dice-1, r-2) + ... + (1/6)P(dice-1, r-6)
```

meaning that you have to loop from `r-6` to `r-1`.

And since you are taking a sum over multiple recursive calls, you have to use an accumulator initialized to 0. (The variable I called `sum`)

EDIT: Click [here](http://ideone.com/SwLvP6) for a complete example, compare to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability+of+10+with+3+dice) to verify the result.